# CSS button align bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I'm developing a `webapp` mobile using the `Bootstrap`. I have a screen with a `text` and a `button`. When the `text is small` the `button` should be on the bottom of the page, but when the `text is large` the `button` should be after to the end of text.

How to do this with `CSS`?

The HTML code:

```
<div id="message" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1 class="subject"></h1>
                    <p class="content"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="elapsed"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button id="delete" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-danger">
                        Excluir
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide HTML and CSS

Comment: you want 2 different things that require 2 different styles on the button. You want both the button to stay relative to text ( if text is ' large ' ) and not to stay relative to the text ( if the text is small ) . that's not possible without jq javascript etc. ( also you should post what you have tried. this is not a code making site )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS? It can't be done. However, it *can* be done with jQuery (assuming you have access).

You fail to include any `text` in your example as reference, so I've added some directly above the button, inside the same `col-xs-12` class. Hopefully any issues you may have through having the text in a different DOM location will be fairly straightforward to solve.

Also, "when the text is small" is arbitrary, so I've used a size of 30px in my example. Feel free to modify this.

With jQuery, it's possible to modify the position of the text / button based on the font-size of the text by using something like:

```
if ($(".text").css('font-size') >= '30px') {
    $(".text").css("float", "left");
}
```

I've created a fiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xng710df/). When the font-size of `.text` is under 30px, the button will sit below the text. When the `font-size` of `.text` is 30px or more, the button will sit to the right.

Hope this helps!